# Google maps markers, close infobox when the mouse leaves the marker and infobox

Tags: google-maps

I want the infobox to be closed when the mouse leaves the marker and infobox area.
The problem is that the way I'm trying to check if the mouse is over the infobox doesn't work.

EDIT:
This is the function I'm using know:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', (function(marker, contentString) {
        return function() {
            ib.close();
        };
    })(marker, contentString));
```

Comment: When/how is the infobox opened?  Is there more than one?

Comment: Also, a functioning jsfiddle featuring your current infobox would help me to give you the help you need

Comment: There is no map at the URL you mentioned; only an error: "google is not defined"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your infobox overlaps the marker, so once it opens it will cause a `mouseout` on the marker, and that will immediately close it.

So you need to also add events to the infobox element.

You can do that on the `domready` event of the infobox, as it is dynamically added to the DOM.
And then you need to put a delay on the mouseout event of the marker which you will clear if the user mouseenters the infobox.

Something like this

```
var ibTimeout;
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function (e) {
    ib.open(theMap, this);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseout", function (e) {
    ibTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        ib.close();
    }, 50);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(ib, 'domready', function(e){
     $('.infobox').on('mouseenter', function(e){
         clearTimeout(ibTimeout);
     }).on('mouseleave', function(e){
         clearTimeout(ibTimeout);
         ib.close();
     });
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/t4cPt/39/

Comment: @gaby-aka-g-petrioli your demo is not working. can please check?

Comment: @Rituparnasonowal updated fiddle.The problem is that the InfoBox plugin is not hosted by google-code anymore but has moved to github.

Comment: @gaby-aka-g-petrioli, yeah I figured that out. Thank you for the nice solution.

Comment: `domready` does not run for me, no matter what I do.  Did they change this?

Comment: @Valachio does the fiddle in the answer not work ? (*works for me*). If it does then the problem is elsewhere. Post a new question with your code if you need further help.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli I ended up solving it some other way.  But thank you so much for the offer of help!

Answer (score 0):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', (function() {        
          infowindow.close();
});

google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'mouseout', (function() {        
           this.close();
});
```